# IMAP email channel adapter throw exception "A5 BAD invalid command or parameters;"

Tags: java, spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap, mail-server

I am using imap-idle-channel-adapter to receive emails in spring integration:

```
A5 SEARCH NOT (ANSWERED) NOT (DELETED) NOT (SEEN) NOT (FLAGGED) ALL
A5 BAD invalid command or parameters
```

seems the imap server regard above commands as invalid, anyone can tell me how to fix ?

My debug messages:

```
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.mxhichina.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK AliYun IMAP Server Ready(10.177.11.50)
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 IDLE XLIST UIDPLUS ID SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=EXTERNAL
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: EXTERNAL
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.mxhichina.com, user=*****, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 OK LOGIN completed
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 IDLE XLIST UIDPLUS ID SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=EXTERNAL
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: EXTERNAL
A3 LIST "" INBOX
* LIST () "/" "INBOX"
A3 OK LIST completed
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A4 SELECT INBOX
* 2 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UNSEEN 0]
* OK [UIDNEXT 25] Predicted next UID.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 2] UIDs valid.
* FLAGS (\Answered \Seen \Deleted \Draft \Flagged)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Seen \Deleted \Draft \Flagged)] Limited.
A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed
A5 SEARCH NOT (ANSWERED) NOT (DELETED) NOT (SEEN) NOT (FLAGGED) ALL
A5 BAD invalid command or parameters
13:41:00.557 WARN  [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter] error occurred in idle task
javax.mail.MessagingException: A5 BAD invalid command or parameters;
```

my configurations

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="mailAdapter"
                                    store-uri="imaps://${username}:${password}@imap.mxhichina.com/INBOX"
                                    channel="inboundChannel"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    should-delete-messages="true"
                                    should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                                    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </util:properties>
```

Comment: Please, add more tags to your question. That doesn't looks like Spring Integration problem. Your IMAP server has some limitations.

Comment: thanks, add tags imap and javamail

Comment: Good. But I still think you should add tag for your email server as well. That might not be a Java client problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT(*****) command is not supported by my mail server, so following command doesn't work

```
A5 SEARCH NOT (ANSWERED) NOT (DELETED) NOT (SEEN) NOT (FLAGGED) ALL
```

So I changed DefaultSearchTermStrategy to my own one, which named UnseenSearchTermStrategy

```
@Component
public class UnseenSearchTermStrategy  implements SearchTermStrategy {
    UnseenSearchTermStrategy(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public SearchTerm generateSearchTerm(Flags flags, Folder folder) {
        return new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
    }
}
```

and following commands will be executed on mail server and works well

```
A5 SEARCH UNSEEN ALL
```

Related topics in stackoverflow
[Using spring integration IMAP adapter, how to fetch an email which was marked "unread" manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690596/using-spring-integration-imap-adapter-how-to-fetch-an-email-which-was-marked-u)